# R annual rate of change (growth rate) with dplyr lag

Tags: r, dplyr

What is a simple way to calculate the annual rate of change of a variable in R, that is not a time series (for example GDP, Inflation, etc)?

Answer (score 3):

The package `dplyr` helps with its `lag()` function, that is not for a ts (time series) data frame. Here an example:

```
#using the library "dplyr"
library(dplyr)
#setting seed
set.seed(20)
#creating a random dataframe
df <- data.frame(date=paste(rep(2000:2017, each=4),"Q",rep(1:4, 18)), GDP= cumsum(sample(c(-0.5, 3), 72, TRUE)))
#calculating the annual percentage change
df <- df %>% mutate(change=(GDP-lag(GDP,4))/lag(GDP,4)*100)
```

In case of monthly data, simply set: `lag(VAR,12)` where VAR stands for the variable of interest

Comment: It's worth noting that base-`R` has a `lag()` function, but it doesn't work the same way. It's therefore essential to insert `library(dplyr)`, otherwise weird results will start appearing.