# Rate of change for 5 months of bimonthly data using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I found this post and solution on annual growth rates using dplyr really helpful:

[R annual rate of change (growth rate) with dplyr lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663814/r-annual-rate-of-change-growth-rate-with-dplyr-lag)

Instead of calculating annual rate of change, I want to calculate month-to-month growth rates for bimonthly data from part of the year, from May to September. I think I figured it out, using the post referenced above as a guide. Here is a reproducible example:

```
#build toy dataset. In contains the Plant ID, leaf length, Sampling Month, and Sampling Time within the month (either T1 or T2)
Plant_ID <- c("365","365","365","365","365","365","365","365","365","365")
Leaf_length <- c(4, 10, 15, 17, 20, 25, 30, 50, 45, 47)
Month <- c(5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9)
Period <- c("T1","T2","T1","T2","T1","T2","T1","T2","T1","T2")

toy_growthrate <- data.frame(Plant_ID, Leaf_length, Month, Period)

#look at dataset
toy_growthrate

#try to calculate bimonthly percentage change
toy_growthrate <- toy_growthrate %>% mutate(change=(Leaf_length-lag(Leaf_length,2))/lag(Leaf_length,2)*100)

#the new column "change" is filled with month-to-month growth
toy_growthrate
```

However, I am still stuck on how to do this month-to-month growth calculation if in certain months I have bimonthly data but in other months I have 4 data points (i.e. weekly data)? Do I need to take averages of the weekly data to convert it to bimonthly so that all months have the same number of data points?

Here is another code example with this new twist:

```
#build toy dataset. In contains the Plant ID, leaf length, Sampling Month, and Sampling Time within the month (T1, T2, T3, T4 in May, T1 and T2 in remaining months)
Plant_ID <- c("365","365","365","365","365","365","365","365","365","365","365","365")
Leaf_length <- c(1,2,4, 10, 15, 17, 20, 25, 30, 50, 45, 47)
Month <- c(5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9)
Period <- c("T1","T2","T3","T4","T1","T2","T1","T2","T1","T2","T1","T2")

toy_growthrate_with_twist <- data.frame(Plant_ID, Leaf_length, Month, Period)

#look at dataset
toy_growthrate_with_twist
```

In this new dataset, there are 4 measurements of Leaf length in May, but only 2 in the remaining months. How can I do the month-to-month growth calculation in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the actual difference between your data and the example you provided. Could you share a minimal example of your real data and the expected output?